# How to hide a UITabBar item?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to create a switch button to hide a UITabBar item. Can you explain me how can I create this?

My switch button must hide the **automatic** item when is on and show it when is off.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

After Some comments by users @switchCTRL , @Ashley Mills  to add diffrent ways to hide and show. you can do subclass of UITabBarController  according to  @switchCTRL

And use like that if you create your `TabbarController` With Code

```
  CustomTabbarViewController *tabbarController  = [[CustomTabbarViewController alloc]init];
    tabbarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:ViewController1,ViewController2,ViewController3,ViewController4,ViewController5 ,nil];
```

if you create in Stroybord just make sure that your `TabbarContoller`'Supercalss is `CustomTabbarViewController`

***CustomTabbarViewController:***

---

**CustomTabbarViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTabbarViewController : UITabBarController

-(void)hideDynamicTabbarItem;
-(void)showDynamicTabbarItem;

@end
```

**CustomTabbarViewController.m**

```
#import "CustomTabbarViewController.h"

@interface CustomTabbarViewController (){
  UIViewController *dynamicController;
}

@end

@implementation CustomTabbarViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


-(void)hideDynamicTabbarItem{
    if (self.viewControllers.count > 2) {
        NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = (NSMutableArray*)self.viewControllers;
        dynamicController = allViewControllers[2];
        [allViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:2];
        self.viewControllers = allViewControllers;
    }
}
-(void)showDynamicTabbarItem{
  
        NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = (NSMutableArray*)self.viewControllers;
        [allViewControllers insertObject:dynamicController atIndex:2];
        self.viewControllers = allViewControllers;
    
}


@end
```

**To Hide:**

```
if ([self.tabBarController isKindOfClass:[CustomTabbarViewController class]]) {
    
    [(CustomTabbarViewController*)self.tabBarController hideDynamicTabbarItem];
}
```

**To Show:**

```
   if ([self.tabBarController isKindOfClass:[CustomTabbarViewController class]]) {
        
        [(CustomTabbarViewController*)self.tabBarController showDynamicTabbarItem];
    }
```

---

**Another Simple Solution but not preferred:**

In your `AppDeleagte.h` file  add `dynamicController`

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
   @property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *dynamicController;
@end
```

**Then when you Hide :**

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                      
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers = (NSMutableArray *) 
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
    
    appDelegate.dynamicController = viewControllers[2]; // to add later
    [viewControllers removeObject:APPDELEGATE.dynamicController];
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```

**And when you show :**

```
  AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSMutableArray *viewControllers = (NSMutableArray *) self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
       [viewControllers insertObject:appDelegate.dynamicController atIndex:2];
        [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```

Comment: Referring to your AppDelegate like that is like using a global variable - bad practice

Comment: May be he need to show it from any place inside app , this can done by more ways , i just give him hints , he can do manager to do this stuff

Comment: Try to store your controller somewhere else than in the AppDelegate. To many unrelated code makes your AppDelegate very messy and hard to understand. You can subclass the TabBar controller and store it there. A "Manager" is also bad practice, there is no need for singletons if you can avoid it.

Comment: @switchCTRL Nice to just keep downVotes , i think you not understand my previous comment

Comment: @switchCTRL Answer updated , id't prefer downVote correct answer even if it not better , just we can say there is better solutions and add ours

Comment: @AshleyMills Answer updated , i don't prefer downVote correct answer even if it not better , just we can say there is better solutions try to enhance

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish The updated solution is much better. Downvotes are the only way to show people the marked solution is not preferred. No one reads the comments if the answer is already accepted.

Comment: When I cal it in viewDidAppear: Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7fc20c841c00> on <TabViewController: 0x7fc20e029400> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 3):

You hav to remove your controller (not the tab directly) from the array of managed controllers by the UITabBarController and re-add it later.

To remove the item:

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = (NSMutableArray *) self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
[viewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:2];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```

Hold a strong reference to your removed controller and re-add it later:

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = (NSMutableArray *) self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
[viewControllers insertObject:yourRemovedController atIndex:2];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```

Comment: Your code to re-add the item doesn't work. What is the "yourRemovedController"

Comment: You need to store the controller somewhere. For examle in a property on the controller with your switch...

Comment: `somewhere`  what this mean please give more details and techniques how to do to show from any place inside app

Comment: The best place to put a reference to the controller you want to hide is in a subclass of the TabBarController. You need to create a subclass of UITabBarController and store it there. Depending on your setup (storyboards or in code) you need to set the class of the UITabBarController to your custom subclass. Now you can access it from everywhere. If you need hide it earlier, for example before the tab bar controller is visible, you can write a settings service and store a 'BOOL' value if the tab should be shown or not.

Comment: Will add a new answer in a few hours

Comment: How can I load the app when the tabbaritem is hide ? in the viewDidLoad.